# Working with Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I'm working on a twisted program that I inherited. I have some code that's currently in the tap.py file, but doesn't belong there. I'm moved it out into it's own file in the same directory, but now the tap file can't find the classes. How would I go about fixing that? I'm pretty green when it comes to python / twisted so don't assume that because something is trivial I didn't over look it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/twistd", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('Twisted==10.2.0', 'twistd')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 461, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1194, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Twisted-10.2.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/twistd", line 19, in <module>
    run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Twisted-10.2.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 27, in run
    app.run(runApp, ServerOptions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Twisted-10.2.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/twisted/application/app.py", line 631, in run
    runApp(config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Twisted-10.2.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
    _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Twisted-10.2.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/twisted/application/app.py", line 374, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Twisted-10.2.0-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/twisted/application/app.py", line 434, in createOrGetApplication
    ser = plg.makeService(self.config.subOptions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lister-0.0dev_r207-py2.6.egg/lister/mailer/tap.py", line 84, in makeService
    smtpFactory = SmtpDaemonFactory()
NameError: global name 'SmtpDaemonFactory' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I feel slightly silly. I fixed it by using the correct import.